# In Android hide some of the texts or views from recent app view

Tags: android, android-security, android-recents, android-task

In android For security reasons I want to hide some of the texts or views , when app is moved to recent apps in task manager. I tried to handle this by below ways but before going to the lifecyle it takes the screen shot for recent app view.
1. Inside `onPause()`
2. Inside `onWindowFocusChanged()`
3. Inside `onUserLeaveHint()`
All the above called after screen shot taken for recent apps
1. Its never been called `onCreateThumbnail()` (I don't want to hide complete screen, only the textviews has to be hidden)
Please anyone have a solution for this issue ?

In Android 8.0 its doing after on pause but earlier versions how to handle.

Comment: You can set visibility Gone inside onPause() method , Have you try it ?

Comment: Before getting into onpause its taking the screen shot. So no use of handling in onpause.

Answer (score 4):

The way I do it is by calling

getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

after setContentView(R.layout.yours) in onCreate().

Comment: Thanks!!! this really helped, I was thinking of hiding the content in onPause and showing in onResume, But adding a flag seems a better solution.